# How can I reduce "follow me" ads in adsense for publishers?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, geotargeting, remarketing

On pages I publish, I have adsense display ads, which often seem to show "follow me" or "remarketing" ads (relevant to the user's recent searches) rather than contextual ads (those relevant to the page in question).  My ad block in this case is 250x250.

How can I reduce the number of follow me ads, and get more page-relevant ads to show?

This is deep content site, and each page is definitely about a specific topic.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do that? Adsense usually shows whatever ads will earn you most.

Comment: The integrity of my pages is more important than revenue.  The ads compliment the pages in question, providing a commercial insight into the same topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there isn't any way to refuse them in Adsense. The "follow me" ads are an option in Adwords and is called "Remarketing".

You can find documentation here:
http://www.google.com/ads/innovations/remarketing.html

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you're using Adsense as a feature of your site and not just as a source of revenue. I would say that's counter-intuitive to the point and purpose of Adsense and software like it. Adsense is working from the wealth of knowledge it has gained about your users and algorithmically finds ads it thinks will get better conversions. Sometimes that means ads relevant to the content of the page, much of the time (in my experience, at least) it means I will see lots of ads for Panama City Beach since Google knows I plan to go there.

Having 100% relevant ads on your page certainly makes sense from the perspective of a content provider. Perhaps there are other products out there (perhaps Google itself could create a spinoff) that would achieve that. But currently Adsense's algorithms don't seem to do that.

Comment: Note: AdSense is advertises to publishers for just this use (context relevant ads).

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to block "follow me" ads.

However, I'm not sure that contextual ads inherently have "more integrity". Ads on any subject can be good or bad.

My advice would be to block all the sensitive categories in "Allow & block ads", as these typically worse adverts. Then keep an eye on the ad review center to block anything that looks spammy.

Comment: "Follow me" ads are unrelated to my page content.  I don't have any sensitive categories: if my page happens to be about alcohol I'd want alcohol ads, not "follow me" ads.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please let me know what is incorrect in the answer.

Comment: @Bryce not sure if you misunderstood but "sensitive categories" is an option in Adsense. And I still maintain that even if you could limit it to contextual ads only, there would still be many ads that do not have "integrity".

Comment: Mr/Ms DisgruntledGoat: yes I understood. I want ads that match the theme of my pages always, even if that topic is sensitive. I do not want ads for shoes on a page about tampons. The tampon page works best when tampon ads are shown. I might some day have a viagra page, in which case I (yes) want viagra ads.